# Check if a node with the same label exists in networkx in python

Tags: python, networkx

I am using the following code to build my graph using  networkx as follows.

```
mylist = [('chocolate_pudding', 6.3), ('tim_tam', 178.5), ('bread', 3.5), 
('chocolate_pudding', 8.5), ('tim_tam', 3.0), ('butter', 204.0)]

G = nx.Graph()

for ele in mylist:
    #if node with ele[0] does not exists, add the new node
         G.add_node(ele[0], weight=ele[1])
    #else, update the weight with the new weight value (weight = existing_weight + ele[1])
```

I want to check if the node with the same label exists before creating a new node. If the node exists I want to update its weight by adding the new value to the existing value.

For example in the above example, I want only 4 nodes `chocolate_pudding, tim_tam, bread, butter` and their weight should be `14.8, 181.5, 3.5, 204.0` respectively.

I did not find a proper way of doing this in networkx. hence please let me know if this is possible to do in networkx?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `ele[0] in G` to check whether a label `ele[0]` is already in there. Updating values are rather straightforward.

```
import networkx as nx
mylist = [('chocolate_pudding', 6.3), ('tim_tam', 178.5), ('bread', 3.5), ('chocolate_pudding', 8.5), ('tim_tam', 3.0), ('butter', 204.0)]

G = nx.Graph()

for ele in mylist: 
     if ele[0] not in G:
         G.add_node(ele[0], weight=ele[1])
     else:
         new_weight = G.nodes[ele[0]]["weight"] + ele[1]
         # set values
         G.node[ele[0]]["weight"] = new_weight

G.nodes(data=True)        
# NodeDataView({'chocolate_pudding': {'weight': 14.8}, 
#               'tim_tam': {'weight': 181.5}, 
#               'bread': {'weight': 3.5}, 
#               'butter': {'weight': 204.0}})
```

**Edit:** This answer is based on networkx 2.0. It seems that before networkx 2.0, `nodes` is only a function rather than an attribute. Thus, you may need to refer to the documentation for how to update nodes. My guess is `G.nodes(data=True)[ele[0]]["weight] = new_weight` would work. Or checkout `set_node_attributes` function.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, I got the following error when running this program `new_weight = G.nodes[ele[0]]["weight"] + ele[1]

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable` Can you please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: let me see. which version of networkx you are using? print(nx.__version__) to see. I am using '2.0'. Try G.nodes()[ele[0]]. I think they might change the API.

Comment: However I still get an error for the edit as `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. I am using conda. Is there a way to upgrade networkx in conda?

Comment: @JCena You can see it here https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#updating-packages

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way is to calculate these values before building the graph

```
from collections import defaultdict
import networkx as nx

mylist = [('chocolate_pudding', 6.3), ('tim_tam', 178.5), ('bread', 3.5), 
('chocolate_pudding', 8.5), ('tim_tam', 3.0), ('butter', 204.0)]

d = defaultdict(int)

for n, w in mylist:
    d[n] += w

G = nx.Graph()

for n, w in d.items():
    G.add_node(n, weight=w)

print(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'weight'))
# {'chocolate_pudding': 14.8, 'tim_tam': 181.5, 'bread': 3.5, 'butter': 204.0}
```